# how to set perticular payment method in magento session programatically in methods.phtml using getsingleton?

Tags: session, methods, payment, overwrite

I am trying to set  perticular payment method in magento session programatically in methods.phtml.I know how to retrive current selected payment method from magento  session using getsingleton.But i am not able to find out how to override the existing selected payment method in magento session.I want to directly Update magento session variable for payement method. Is there anything like "Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setMethod('$method')". I have tried every other solution.Please please help to do this.If there is any function like this then please help me.. ..

Comment: I just want to set payment method in magento session programatically ..

Comment: try Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setMethod($method);